# google qpx query in Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

i'm tryng to request a (simple) flight-query trough google flight service via Apps Script

this is my code

```
    function myFunction() {
    var api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var url2= "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=" + api_key;
    var param2 ={
      "method" : "POST",
      "contentType":"application/json",
      "headers" : {"Content-Type": "application/json"
     },
      "request": {"passengers": {"adultCount": 1},
      "slice": [{"origin": "BOS","destination": "LAX","date": "2015-03-01"}]
      },
       muteHttpExceptions : true
    }; 
    try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2,param2);  
      Logger.log(response)
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e)
      }
    }
```

this request send me error code

```
"error": {"errors": [{
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Invalid inputs: received empty request."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid inputs: received empty request."
 }
```

The qpx Api is loaded in my developer console....anyone has any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: check this page: https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/faq#q25 It might be because of an invalid API key. You can also try sending a request as mentioned in this page: https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/requests

Answer (score 0):

Two things, the body of the request must be specified with the "payload" property, not "request", and you must actually convert your Javascript Object to a JSON string before posting it.  (You also don't need the "headers" property, "contentType" will suffice, but I don't think it hurts anything)

```
var param2 ={
  "method" : "post",
  "contentType":"application/json",
  "payload": JSON.stringify({"passengers": {"adultCount": 1},
                             "slice": [{"origin": "BOS",
                                        "destination": "LAX",
                                        "date": "2015-03-01"
                                      }]
                             }
                           ),
   muteHttpExceptions : true
};
```

It's all documented here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)

However, the need to JSON.stringify()  usually throws people off, if you pass a Javascript Object directly in the payload it is posted as form-encoded key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much...you put me in the right direction!
 this is the right syntax:

```
var param2 ={
  "method" : "post",
  "contentType":"application/json",
  "payload": JSON.stringify
              (
              {"request":
                             {"passengers": {"adultCount": 1},
                             "slice": [{"origin": "BOS",
                                        "destination": "LAX",
                                        "date": "2015-03-01"
                                      }]
                             }
              }
              ),
   muteHttpExceptions : true
};
```